# Search query in mongodb using regular expression

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im building a website, using nodejs, expressjs, mongodb, mongoose, body-parser and etc..

basically i've created a search function, where you can search for users and basically it works, but the problem is, it is case-sensitive, i want to search for the user using case-insensitive.

I have found a solution here in stack overflow and tried it on my mongo shell. this is the command

```
    db.loginusers.find({
    $or: 
    [

        {"firstname": {$regex: /^PIa$/i}}, 
        {"lastname": {$regex: /^NAtUrE$/i}}

    ]
})
```

this works on mongoshell. so when i try to put this on my JS file,

```
app.post("/searchresult", function(req, res){
    var thename = req.body.thename;
    LoginUser.find({
        $or: [

            {"firstname": {$regex: /^thename$/i}},
            {"lastname": {$regex: /^thename$/i}}
        ]
    }, function(err, searchedUser){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {
            res.render("searchprofile", {foundUser: searchedUser});
        }
    });
});
```

it is not working, eventhough i tried to put the correct case on the name it is not functioning..

my question is, do i need to do something before i use the regex on my JS file?

THank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `thename` is a variable, I think that's the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

can try it with `$options:'i"`

```
LoginUser.find({
  $or: [
    {'firstname': {$options:'i', $regex: 'PIa'}}, 
    {'lastname':  {$options:'i', $regex: 'NAtUrE'}}
  ]
})
```

or:

```
LoginUser.find({
  $or: [
    {'firstname': {$regex: /PIa/i}}, 
    {'lastname':  {$regex: /NAtUrE/i}}
  ]
})
```

also read docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

it has some nice features like: `$nin`, `$options: 'six'`

Comment: @John I think Your query was: ^something$  it means: starts with and ends with. so it's same as {firstname: 'something'}, but in Shaishab's answer he just defined pattern that works as: LIKE '%something%' operator in mysql

Comment: @num8er, ok cool, thanks bro. but could you tell me whats more efficient? shaishabs answer or chridam answer? chridam answer works too.

Comment: @num8er described it. also can use like: `$regex: /PIa/i` instead of `/^PIa$/i` that should be work.

Comment: @John it's both same idea. One has made regexp object, other used mongodb's regex syntax with option. but I prefer Shaishab's answer, cuz I'm not fan of creating additional elements in code and consume memory

Comment: @num8er The `RegExp` is necessary because it allows variables to be used as the regex pattern. The above answer assumes static patterns `/PIa/` and `/NAtUrE/` so that will not work given a variable search pattern, which is where the OP's problem lies.

Comment: Dear @chridam, You're best (;

Answer (score 2):

Because `thename` is a variable, use the [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object constructor to create a regex instance off the variable that you can then use in your query as:

```
var rgx = new RegExp("^"+ thename +"$", "i");
LoginUser.find({
    "$or": [
        {"firstname": rgx },
        {"lastname": rgx }
    ]
}, callback);
```